# app crashes on production but not in development - android app

Tags: android, kotlin

My Project structure:
1- Kotlin app lib. 
2-Java app calling methods from Kotlin lib.

From Java app I'm calling some methods from Kotlin lib. in development all works good and methods called successfully. after generating apk app starts with splash screen then crashes after getting location,
specifically when calling methods from Kotlin lib.

I think I missed something when generating apk with App and lib. 
I tried this example and another about proguardFiles but no new result:

https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-creating-a-multi-project-build/

the error:

```
2020-05-28 13:22:29.970 339-339/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.app, PID: 339
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method asAttributeSet(Lh/a/a/a;)Landroid/util/AttributeSet; in class Landroid/util/Xml; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.util.Xml' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)
        at c.a.n.g.inflate()
 at  ui.activity.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu()
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3183)
        at androidx.fragment.app.d.onCreatePanelMenu()
        at c.a.n.i.onCreatePanelMenu()
        at androidx.appcompat.app.f$j.onCreatePanelMenu()
        at c.a.n.i.onCreatePanelMenu()
        at androidx.appcompat.app.i.o()
        at androidx.appcompat.app.i$a.run()
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: disable obfuscation and try again

Comment: PROGUARD!, https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

Comment: @Hooman , I added  `-dontobfuscate` in proguard-rules.pro and finally worked , thanks  , How to mark your comment as answer :)

Comment: obfuscate is a good thing for preventing your app from reverse engineering. it's better to add custom rules and keep obfuscating